# Ubuntu stopped detecting tap-to-click

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, libinput

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  with libinput. Today for some unkown reason it stopped detecting touch-to-tap. I have to press heavily on the touchpad for a click to be detected. It is very annoying. Everything else works fine on the touchpad (scrolling, pointer motion etc)

My laptop is an Acer Predator 300.

Any idea?

Comment: Check whether Tap to click is enabled or not under Settings -> Devices -> Mouse and Touchpad

Comment: Have you tried to reboot and see if the problem is cleared?

Comment: I checked and it says on
Also tried to reboot many times and still same :/
Also now (maybe not relevant to this problem) sometimes my caps lock gets flipped (it shows locked but it acts as unlocked and vice verse). Did something like this happen to you before?